# How do I use DynamoDB for geo-location based queries?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, geospatial, data-modeling, nosql

I'm designing a photo sharing app (location based). I plan to use AWS Cognito for authentication/authorization, DynamoDB for persistent data, S3 for file storage, and Lambda + API Gateway for web services.

These are the key use-cases/access patterns (other than sign-up/sign-in):

1. User creates a post: title, media, location (lat,lon)
2. Users fetch a list of posts closest to their geo-location (newest first)

These are the Tables that I'm going to create:

```
Users table
hash-key=userID from cognito

Posts table
hash-key=userID from cognito
range-key=date
other-attributes=title, image-s3-path, ge-location
```

What is the best way to implement a query (perhaps with the help of adding LSI, GSI, or even more tables), so that the result is a collection of posts based on users's current location. Eg. show only posts within 10 km of radius, sorted by newest first.

Comment: Have you checked this: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/geo-library-for-amazon-dynamodb-part-1-table-structure/ ?

Answer (score 2):

You mentioned that your use case is `users can retrieve posts closest to their location` so that says that a good hash key for posts would be one that partitions data by spacial coordinates, not by user id.

I would look into geo hashing and using something like that for keys. You want to pick a partition key that gives good spatial partitioni g such that the posts are uniformly distributed, and there are relatively few of them in each partition key.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Assuming that I can figure out a way to convert {lat,lon} -> geo-hashed-key and I'll use this as a hash-key of my DynamoDB table. I can send the user's current location to the backend and then search the relevant item in the table. The result is supposed to be a list of items, ordered by nearest to farthest. Is there a way to achieve this ?

Comment: So you'll want to use a wider, more coarse, area as the hash key. And place all items with locations in that area as items with that hadh key and a range key of the exact location in the table. When you query to determine posts near by you execute a few queries, for the "same area" and neighbours. Think of it as overlapping cells or arbitrary radius.

Comment: This means that I need to have some kind of backend API (perhaps powered by Lambda) to achieve this result. ie. merging the results of multiple queries, sorting them, and then composing a response for the client app. Are there any other AWS services that I should look into for better implementation ?

Comment: Spot on! Whether you use Lambda or an EC2 cacked backend, that's where you'll be processing the query results to return the right results. Is far as other services, you should definitely cache your results so look into ElasticCache

Comment: The comments section is for commenting on an answer. If your comments represent a different question, I recommend asking a new question because that way other people can benefit from the answers (also consider up voting answers if you found them helpful)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have upvoted the answer and will create a separate question.

Answer (score 2):

I would consider using ElasticSearch, since it [natively supports geohashing](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-geohashgrid-aggregation.html)